# IllegalStateException: The Specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()

Tags: android

Hey guys first of all sorry for my bad english (i'm not a native speaker) and I am aware of that this question has been asked several times before. Since the solution is very individual and i'm bit confused.

The problem is: I am trying to add several views(TextView, View) to a LinearLayout. Adding of first two components is working fine, but for the third view got an exception. Here is my code

```
 if(textView_value != null) {
        textView_value = null;
    }

    textView_value = new TextView(this);
    textView_value.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView_value.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

linearLayout.addView(textView_value);

View view = new View(this);
     view.setLayoutParams(...);
     ...
linearLayout.addView(view);

textView_value = new TextView(this);
...

linearLayout.addView(textView_value); // Here is the app crashing :(
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the same view more than once. If you want add the same reference, first you need to remove it from the viewgroup and add. So Change these two lines

```
textView_value = new TextView(this);
linearLayout.addView(textView_value);
```

as

```
TextView textView_value1 = new TextView(this);
linearLayout.addView(textView_value1);
```

Comment: Thank you. But what should I do, if i want add 10000 TextView, for example in a loop?? Should i declare 1000 TextView references. 
After linearLayout.addView(textView); 

Can't i set the reference NULL and then reuse it??

Comment: Why are you adding views to layout? Better to use Listview instead..It will handle the re-usability of views

Comment: Generally you're right, but my job is it to do so... And in my case it make more since. I've to add multiple textView in horizontal direction in a layout...

Comment: Yes, you can add any number of views to the viewgroup

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
textView_value = new TextView(this);
```

second line causing issue due to same object is adding again in LinerLayout.

Use another name for new TextView object as:

```
TextView textView_value_one = new TextView(this);
...
linearLayout.addView(textView_value_one);
```